# 0xc000007b error in Visual Studio project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, dll

I've created my C++ aplication that loads 2 DLLs: 1 wrriten in MASM assembler and the second written in C++. It uses Windows Forms' UI and works fine, but only on my computer.

On computers of all of my friends it causes 0xc000007b error that I'm unable to solve. I read everything I found about this error. Nothing helps.

I tried to do anything with manifests options in linker section, I tried to add lot of different DLLs to folder with project, I tried to use Debug and Release versions, I tried to change it to x64 version (without success).
I used dependency walker, it shows lot of DLLs missing (even though on my computer program works.) - I don't know what to do with this.
[image: Errors]

Do you have any idea? In my application I use only Windows Forms, fstream, msclr\marshal_cppstd.h and my DLLs.

Comment: does the target PC have the MSVC 2012 runtime library and the .Net framework installed?

Comment: I'm not sure. But I have to create application that works even on clean Windows installation. What should I add to project?

Comment: You'd need to build an installer to install the other libraries needed. Sad to say I'm weak on that, but it should be searchable. Recommend testing the theory first with a manual install to a clean machine. One that you can easily restore to the initial state for future testing, if possible. Sucks to run out of test computers before you've built a workable formula.

Comment: I tried to find needed dlls everywhere - the problem is: I don't know what to include. Making installer is not a problem. Do you have any idea how can I check what DLLs I need to import?

Comment: Hmya, you are looking in the completely wrong corner for this problem.  It is not a missing DLL error, you either created or copied an executable file that is not compatible with your friend's machine.  Usually because it is very old, like XP or not a 64-bit machine.

Comment: They tested in on Windows 7, Windows 8, Windows 10. Didn't work.